# A one to one function $f: U \subset \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^m$ with surjective derivative is a global diffeomorphism onto its image

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, derivatives, differential-topology

I just started doing exercises on the Inverse Function Theorem and I think this is probably a pretty simple application of it, but I just wanted to check my reasoning.

The condition that the derivative of $f$ is surjective tells us that at every $p \in U$, the Jacobian matrix has non zero determinant (since the matrix has full rank because of surjectivity). Then by the inverse function theorem $f$ is a local diffeomorphism. Since $f$ is injective, it's restriction to its image is bijective and hence has an inverse, which is locally smooth near any $p \in U$ again by the inverse function theorem, which then proves that $f^{-1}$ is smooth as well, therefore $f$ is a global diffeomorphism onto its image.

Is all of that correct, can anything be improved? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: It is all correct, but it can be simplified. Note that simply being injective and surjective (once restricted to its image), means $f^{-1}$ exists. And by a single application of the inverse function theorem, $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at every point, which makes $f$ a diffeomorphism.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thanks! If you wanna post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.